# How do I set proxy in Nuxt3?

Tags: vue.js, proxy, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I try to start a nuxt3 program, now I want to set server proxy.
A request to http://localhost:3000/api/v1 is supposed to return a response from our backend server on http://39.98.58.238:8594 , but now it gives me a 404 page.

At first, I follow the vite.js docs to set nuxt.config.js file

nuxt.config.js

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({  
  ...  
  vite: {
    server: {
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://39.98.58.238:8594',
          changeOrigin: true,
          rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
        }
      },
    }
  },
})
```

page

```
<script setup>
  async function test() {
   await usefetch('/api/v1/xxx')
  }
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="test">check</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

It didn't work, my request returned a 404 page.
Then I try to follow this issue: [text](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/8303), do not use vite proxy

nuxt.config.js

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    devProxy: {
        '/api/': {
            target: 'http://39.98.58.238:8594/',
            changeOrigin: true
        }
    }
  }
})
```

But it's still not work. What can I do to solve the problem? Thanks!!!

Comment: try to change `/api/` to `/api/v1` in your devProxy config inside nuxt.config.js. [Look here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15388)

Answer (score 10):

For those who are still wondering how to do this in **production mode**. I believe the answer is

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  nitro: {
    routeRules: {
      '/proxy/example': { proxy: 'http://39.98.58.238:8594' },
      "/proxy/**": { proxy: '/api/**' },
    }
  }
})
```

You can find the [docs here](https://nitro.unjs.io/config#routerules) ⚠️ EXPERIMENTAL!

Answer (score 4):

```js
   export default defineNuxtConfig({  
        nitro: {
            devProxy: {
                "/devApi": {
                    target:"your url",
                    changeOrigin: true,
                    prependPath: true,
                }
            }
        },
    })
```

Comment: Works but not for SSR

Answer (score 3):

**Nuxt v3.11**

**.env**

```
API_URL="https://example.com/api/**"
```

**env.d.ts**

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly API_URL: string;
}

interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv;
}
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  routeRules: {
    "/api/**": { proxy: import.meta.env.API_URL },
  },
});
```

---

**Benefits of this approach**

**Works both on the server side and on the client side. You can check using the *ssr* flag in *defineNuxtConfig***

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  ssr: false,
  routeRules: {
    "/api/**": { proxy: import.meta.env.API_URL },
  },
});
```

---

**Allows you to do profiling.**

**.env.production**

```
API_URL="https://example.com/api/**"
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nuxt dev --dotenv .env",
  "build:dev": "nuxt build --dotenv .env",
  "preview:dev": "nuxt preview --dotenv .env",
  "generate:dev": "nuxt generate --dotenv .env",
  "build": "nuxt build --dotenv .env.production",
  "preview": "nuxt preview --dotenv .env.production",
  "generate": "nuxt generate --dotenv .env.production",
  "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
},
```

---

**Possibility of using several proxies.**

**.env**

```
API_URL="https://example.com/api/**"
API_URL_V2="https://example.com/api/v2/**"
```

**env.d.ts**

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly API_URL: string;
  readonly API_URL_V2: string;
}

interface ImportMeta {
  readonly env: ImportMetaEnv;
}
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  routeRules: {
    "/api/**": { proxy: import.meta.env.API_URL },
    "/api/v2/**": { proxy: import.meta.env.API_URL_V2 },
  },
});
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your contribution to StackOverflow. Your answer looks good but could be improved by an explanation of the benefit of this approach over the other answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

For your example, it should be

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    nitro: {
        devProxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://39.98.58.238:8594/api',
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Check the object key '/api' and the "target: '..../api'" property.