# Nuxt 3 proxy production configuration

Tags: proxy, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3, nitro

I have configured my next.config.ts like this:

```
nitro: {
    devProxy: {
      "/auth": {
        target: "http://example.com:8000/auth", 
        changeOrigin: true,
        prependPath: true,
      },
      "/test": {
        target: "http://example.com:8000/test", 
        changeOrigin: true,
        prependPath: true,
      },
      "/prod": {
        target: "http://example.com:8000/prod", 
        changeOrigin: true,
        prependPath: true,
      },
    }
  }
```

And when i write

```
npm run generate
```

and write

```
npx serve .output/public
```

to check builded project in production, it returns 404 error and responce is html, but should be JSON object. I understand that devProxy is only for development, but how can i handle proxy in production?

I've searched and saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570188/how-do-i-set-proxy-in-nuxt3) and i've tried vite config but it didnt work even in dev mode, and i also tried nitro routeRules like

```
nitro: {
    routeRules: {
      "/auth/api/login": { proxy: {
        to: 'http://example.com:8000/auth/api/login',
      } },
      '/test/api/sites': {
        proxy: 'http://example.com:8000/test/api/sites'
      },
      '/prod/api/sites': {
        proxy: 'http://example.com:8000/prod/api/sites'
      }
    }
  }
```

And it worked in dev, but not in production. If i write like:

```
nitro: {
    routeRules: {
      "/auth/**": { proxy: {
        to: 'http://example.com:8000/auth/**'
      } },
    }
  }
```

It wont work too.

Comment: My below answer did not help you? was not correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. nitro dev proxy just works in developer mode thus after genrate it will not work any more.
2. the latest nitro version ( Nitro 2.6.3) proxy untill now does not work properly. I left several message on github nuxt3 and nitro. Maybe in next version of nitro it will be solved.
3. After more than one week struggeling, I find best solution is the using of "nuxt-proxy". you can find it here
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-proxy
4. It is simple to use.

```
  proxy: {
    options: {
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:yourport',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/login': '/api/login',
        and your rest api's routes  

      },
      pathFilter: [
        '/api/login',
        and your rest api's routs
      ]
    }
  },
```

good lock

Comment: Thanks, man! But it didnt help as well. It works in dev mode, but when i generate it's still not working

Comment: read the nitro proxy. according to my checking and nitro documents, nitro devproxy works just in "npm run dev". Do not waste your time just like me.

Comment: so how can i make requests in production mode?

Comment: with the  plugin mentioned above, and the code that i gave. npm run build and npm run generate both works properly. there is also document in the plugin.